# Как сохранить изображение в Yii2, если файл находится в $_FILES?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Как сохранить изображение в Yii2, если файл находится в $_FILES?

Файлы грузятся на сайт с помощью ajax. И находятся в глобальном массиве $_FILES

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html, https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide-ru/input-file-upload/,  http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15956&start=10

Comment: В примере используется поле fileInput(), а у меня файлы грузятся на сайт с помощью ajax.

Comment: Не вижу проблем. Абсолютно также используешь `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');` .... для ajax надо не забыть настройки `processData: false,
      contentType: false` .

Comment: он у меня UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file'); возвращает null
В $_POST только название атрибута хранится. Ajax все нормально на сервер передает. Я конечно могу средствами php сохранить, но хотелось бы это реализовать с помощью Yii

Comment: добавь в вопрос, что у тебя написано в модели, контроллере и в шаблоне с ajax